Helmchart rendering questions
I have Deployment helm chart looks like this:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      ...
      template:
        spec:
          ...
          containers:
            - args:
                {{- toYaml .Values.args | nindent 12 }}
              command:
                {{- toYaml .Values.command | nindent 12 }}
              name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              securityContext:
                {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
              envFrom:
                - configMapRef:
                    name: {{ include "helm.fullname" . }}
                - secretRef:
                    name: {{ include "helm.fullname" . }}
              resources:
                {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
              ports:
                - name: web
                  containerPort: {{ .Values.containerPort }}
                  protocol: TCP
              livenessProbe:
                {{- toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | nindent 12 }}
              readinessProbe:
                {{- toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | nindent 12 }}

and values.yaml file:
    ...
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: https
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 60
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 30
    
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: https
      initialDelaySeconds: 120
      periodSeconds: 60
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 30
    ...

the resulting manifest shown in ArgoCD is:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: xxx
              value: >-
                xxx
            ...
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: xxx
            - secretRef:
                name: xxx
          image: >-
            gcr.io/xxx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: my-application-helm-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /app-health/my-application-helm-app/livez
              port: 15020
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /app-health/my-application-helm-app/readyz
              port: 15020
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 1G
            requests:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 1G
          securityContext:
            privileged: false
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
              name: kube-api-access-kpchg
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: xxx
              ...

I have two questions:

I expect the path of liveness & readiness probe to be /actuator/health, but instead they are /app-health/my-application-helm-app/readyz, as a result the Pod is failing. What is causing this discrepancy?

On one hand, the some keys in Deployment helm chart are missing in rendered manifest, such as "args" and "command". On the other hand, some keys in the rendered manifest are not present in Deployment helm chart, such as terminationMessagePath, terminationMessagePolicy, volumeMounts. why does this happened?



1/ this doesn't make sense. You're not looking at the right values.yaml or Chart. Or you have some process that modified Pods on the fly in the cluster. Try rendering in local maybe to check?

2/ missing Argos or command in the deployed view (assuming ArgoCD says everything is synced, no diff, right?) makes me think again that you're not looking a the right Chart/values. Some of the additional keys are to be expected, they're added by K8S itself but definitely not the volumeMounts.

Regarding 1) what is the output of command helm template when you run it in your local machine? Are the probes rendered with the expected values?

This setup looks like you're trying to pass the entire YAML structure as Helm values, and then trying to replay every individual item via templating.  If the configuration layer includes every Kubernetes value, can you skip Helm and just use kubectl apply to deploy the YAML manifests?

@GaëlJ I got the expect probes when rendering in local: "path: /actuator/health". ArgoCD shows the pod in the remote cluster is in "Degraded" status and istio_proxy log shows "Prober does not exists url /app-health/my-application-helm-app/readyz"

@@Rui Jarimba I got the expect probes when rendering in local: "path: /actuator/health".

Check the metadata on the live manifests, you may find a hint about what is modifying your manifests then. Or ask your ops/infra team. Someone must know something about this..

The issue is resolved. It was due to incorrect port specified in the values.yaml. It should be 8080 instead of https.
the paths of the probes in Pod manifest are fine. these probes are not application probes but the ones injected by istio.
